# This API call requires a valid app_id

Tags: facebook

I got something wierd going on. I have 2 Facebook API calls (using the Facebook PHP-SDK) next to each other. The first call goes fine, but the second throws an exception:

"This API call requires a valid app_id"

Previous to the API Call I requested an Access Token with offline_access and publish_stream. The token is valid because API calls next to this "problem call" will do fine. to make things clear, a small snippet of my code:

```
            // this call goes fine!
            $user_info = $this->facebook->api('/'.$user_id );

            // create the wallpost for Facebook
            $wallpost = array(
                'message' => 'some message', 
                'name' => 'Shoppe', 
                'caption' => "Ik heb een product toegevoegd", 
                'link' => site_url(), 
                'description' => $description, 
                'picture' => site_url("assets/img/logo.png")
            );

            // this throws an exception "This API call requires a valid app_id"             
            $result = $this->facebook->api('/'.$user_id.'/feed/','post',json_encode($wallpost) );
```

$user_id is valid value, so is all the info in the $wallpost

Answer (score 0):

I don't know PHP so the details of string concat are lost on me, but the first thing that popped into my head reading this is that your request string on the POST may not be formatted like you think it is so PHP gets a malformed request, cannot find the app ID and throws you an error.

I would suggest taking the string you are creating for the api() call and printing it out before making the call and making sure it looks exactly like it is suppose to look before going over the wire.